# Create an HTML page that can be updated by python

Tags: python, html

I have a UDP packet stream that I am intercepting and then processing to retrieve data from, I would then like to manipulate this data and display it on an HTML page, but this data will be changing approximately 50 times a second and therefore the HTML page will frequently need to be updated.

I also considered processing and then storing each packet as a JSON file and then allowing a JavaScript file to interpret the file but from what I have read you can not use a local JSON file in an HTML file. Some guidance in the correct direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are not using any framework, here is a reference http://www.askyb.com/javascript/load-json-file-locally-by-js-without-jquery/

Comment: This question is too broad for Stack Overflow format, but I'd use websockets with a Javascript client instead of constantly updating the HTML.